# how to get sum of two jtextfield values divide another jtxt value in jtxtfield

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I need to get sum two value and divide one value and show the result in Jtxtfield
I use this code

```
    {
    int num1,num2,num3,sum;
    num1=Integer.parseInt(PB_cash.getText());
    num2=Integer.parseInt(DC_cash.getText());
    num3=Integer.parseInt(BD_cash.getText());
    sum=num1+num2-num3;
    HB_cash.setText(" "+sum);
    }
```

I tried it from without database connection and it works well
but connection with database it will get runtime error

this is the error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 77000"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at bankapplication.Withdrawal_Interface.jButton7ActionPerformed(Withdrawal_Interface.java:758)
at bankapplication.Withdrawal_Interface.access$400(Withdrawal_Interface.java:30)
at bankapplication.Withdrawal_Interface$5.actionPerformed(Withdrawal_Interface.java:502)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
```

Plz help me to fix this problem
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the exception you received, you can not have a space in the string numerical value sent to the: **Integer.parseInt()** method:

Your exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 77000"
```

Use the String.trim() method to remove tabs and whitespaces:

```
{
    int num1,num2,num3,sum;
    num1=Integer.parseInt(PB_cash.getText().trim());
    num2=Integer.parseInt(DC_cash.getText().trim());
    num3=Integer.parseInt(BD_cash.getText().trim());
    sum=num1+num2-num3;
    HB_cash.setText(" " + String.valueOf(sum)); //why you want the space is beyond me :)
}
```

On another note, looking at your JTextField names, it looks like cash is actually to be eventually supplied. Consider using a **float** or **double** data type instead of **int**. That way you can also supply monetary values with decimals like: `5.99`.